# How to do clustering with k-means algorithm for an imported data set with proper scaling of both axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, sklearn-pandas

I m new to data science and python, and jupyter notebook, I m currently studying how to do k means clustering on a data set. I came across ways in which can introduce data

```
Data = {'x': [25,34,22,27,33,33,31,22,35,34,67,54,57,43,50,57,59,52,65,47,49,48,35,33,44,45,38,43,51,46],
        'y': [79,51,53,78,59,74,73,57,69,75,51,32,40,47,53,36,35,58,59,50,25,20,14,12,20,5,29,27,8,7]
       }

df = DataFrame(Data,columns=['x','y'])
```

and use of blobs

```
data = make_blobs(n_samples=200, n_features=2, centers=4, cluster_std=1.6, random_state=50)
```

but I would like to know how to do a proper code with a csv file imported from my computer and do a k means with scaling, thank you in advance, I could not find relevant blogs to help me

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Dulangi/Downloads/winequality-red.csv")
data
data["alcohol"]=data["alcohol"]/data["alcohol"].max()
data["quality"]=data["quality"]/data["quality"].max()
plt.scatter(data["alcohol"],data['quality'])
plt.xlabel("alcohol")
plt.ylabel('quality')
plt.show()
x=data.copy()

kmeans=KMeans(2)
kmeans.fit(x)

clusters=x.copy()
clusters['cluster_pred']=kmeans.fit_predict(x)

plt.scatter(clusters["alcohol"],clusters['quality'],c=clusters['cluster_pred'],cmap='rainbow')
plt.xlabel("alcohol")
plt.ylabel('quality')
plt.show()

from sklearn import preprocessing
x_scaled=preprocessing.scale(x)
#x_scaled

wcss=[]

for i in range(1,30):
    kmeans=KMeans(i)
    kmeans.fit(x_scaled)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    wcss


    plt.plot(range(1,30),wcss)
    plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
    plt.ylabel('WCSS')
    plt.show()
```

This is what i tried
the error i got

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d4955ce8615e> in <module>
     39 
     40 
---> 41     plt.plot(range(1,30),wcss)
     42     plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
     43     plt.ylabel('WCSS')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2787     return gca().plot(
   2788         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2789         is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2790 
   2791 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1664         """
   1665         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D._alias_map)
-> 1666         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1667         for line in lines:
   1668             self.add_line(line)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    223                 this += args[0],
    224                 args = args[1:]
--> 225             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    226 
    227     def get_next_color(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    389             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    390 
--> 391         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    392 
 393         if self.command == 'plot':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    268         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    269             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension, but "
--> 270                              "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
    271         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    272             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (29,) and (1,)
```

Comment: Your question is too generic and open-ended. Can elaborate more and what have you done till now.
There are too many blog/resources/packages available for this. A simple search with text 'k means with scaling with csv' gave good tutorials. And at top one in google search is https://www.kaggle.com/prakharrathi25/weather-data-clustering-using-k-means

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do by using scikit-Learn

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

df=pd.DataFrame(data,index=None)
df.head()
```

Check if rows contain any null values

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

Drop all the rows with null values if any

```
df_numeric.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Normalize data

Normalize the data with MinMax scaling provided by sklearn

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
minmax_processed = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df.drop('title',axis=1))
df_numeric_scaled = pd.DataFrame(minmax_processed, index=df.index, columns=df.columns[:-1])
df_numeric_scaled.head()


from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

Apply K-Means Clustering

What k to choose?

Let's fit cluster size 1 to 20 on our data and take a look at the corresponding score value.

```
Nc = range(1, 20)

kmeans = [KMeans(n_clusters=i) for i in Nc]

score = [kmeans[i].fit(df_numeric_scaled).score(df_numeric_scaled) for i in range(len(kmeans))]
```

These score values signify how far our observations are from the cluster center. We want to keep this score value around 0. A large positive or a large negative value would indicate that the cluster center is far from the observations.

Based on these scores value, we plot an Elbow curve to decide which cluster size is optimal. Note that we are dealing with tradeoff between cluster size(hence the computation required) and the relative accuracy.

```
import matplotlib as pl
pl.plot(Nc,score)
pl.xlabel('Number of Clusters')
pl.ylabel('Score')
pl.title('Elbow Curve')
pl.show()
```

Fit K-Means for clustering with k=5

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmeans.fit(df_numeric_scaled)
df['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
df.head()
```

Comment: Means much for a beginner this helping hand

Comment: import matplotlib as pl should be import matplotlib.pyplot as pl